# Specify diff options for dpkg's config file prompt

Tags: dpkg

When a conffile is modified, `dpkg` gives you a prompt asking what to do:

```
Configuration file '/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** ssl.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

When you select `D`, it runs `diff -Nu` on the current and new configuration file.

**How do you specify different `diff` options?** In particular, I'd often like to specify `-b`. (Obviously, you can re-run diff by hand, but that's far less convenient.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can not; the diff options are hardcoded in `dpkg`'s source. From [`src/configure.c`](http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/1.18.1/src/configure.c/#L198):

```c
            /* Child process. */
            char cmdbuf[1024];

            sprintf(cmdbuf, DIFF " -Nu %.250s %.250s | %.250s",
                    str_quote_meta(old), str_quote_meta(new),
                    command_get_pager());

            command_shell(cmdbuf, _("conffile difference visualizer"));
```

`DIFF` is a macro from [`lib/dpkg/dpkg.h`](http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/1.18.1/lib/dpkg/dpkg.h/#L112) and is just defined as `"diff"`. So that's `diff -Nu` hardcoded.

This is probably [Debian bug #380332](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=380332).